# What part of the "Ruby Rhod appearing on the menu screen of The Fifth Element" question needs more focus?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

This is regarding the question: [What is the significance of Ruby Rhod appearing on the menu screen of "The Fifth Element" video game?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/275515/7957)

It was [closed as "needs more focus"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/200249) and [left closed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/200254) [twice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/200267) in the reopen review queue. I'm assuming it was closed because there are multiple questions in it. The gist of the question is that it's asking what's the deal with or what's the significance of Ruby Rhod's appearance on the menu screen. All the other questions are sub-questions that are relevant to answering the main question and are not asking for something completely unrelated.

I have edited the sub-questions to clarify their connection to the main question. If it still needs more focus in its present state,  **what about it makes it not focused? And how can it be improved to get it reopened?**

Comment: It's been reopened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In its [original form](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/275515/1) this question was ghastly. It was poorly written and barely coherent. Several close votes occurred before I got a chance to edit it.

> **Fifth element ps2 question**
>
> In 3:00
>
> Why the menu choice is with the character Rugby? Why Rugby runs
> away,where is he going?where is this place he is?
>
> Does the player character enters inside him?
>
> I can’t understand.

Even after my edit it carried on attracting close votes and eventually got closed. GalacticNinja then tweaked the title and made a few cosmetic changes and it's since been reopened.

I don't think it's a great question, but the fact that it's answerable goes a long way to improving the chances of it being reopened. They can't all be winners, but at least we were able to salvage it.